# Slide Transition Effect For Testimonial

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a testimonial slider on this page here: http://www.inpha.co/demo.html which i need to make it automatically slide by itself. if you can please take a look at the demo page i did on my website and see what's missing, that'l be great. i tried several things to no avail. I have provided all the codes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: please provide the other details like which carousel control you are using. Otherwise it will be impossible to help you here.

Comment: *"why should i care about other users"*...then why should we care about your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code on form load. Or just execute it in chrome developer console once the page loads

```
setInterval((function(){
 var count = 0;
 return function(){
   count = (count % 4) + 1;
   document.getElementById('slide_2_' + count).checked = true;
 }
})(), 2000)
```

Comment: didn't quite understand what you meant in "Add the following code on form load"? where should i place the code you provided me in: HTML or CSS? and where exactly should i insert it? plz specify more. thx

Comment: You should add it in script tag of your HTML.

Comment: thx but i don't need it anymore. i have figured out another way